# httpd.conf configured mod_rewrite don't work correctly

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First of all, I searched in the internet (including stackoverflow) about this and don't found any solution.

I configured my httpd.conf:

- Uncommenting `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
- Putting `AllowOverride All`

I put the .htaccess inside my `htdocs` directory, with this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^apresentacao/?$ /apresentacao.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^consultoria/?$ /consultoria.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^software+escolar/gestao+escolar/?$ /escolar.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

What Am I doing wrong on the `.htaccess`?

edited.

I try to access the following url: `www.mydomain.com/software+escolar/gestao+escolar/` and it don't work.

I need to use the character + (plus) to separate the names of the url.

I still can't access any page that I put in the `.htaccess`.

Comment: Which URL did you try? And what error did you get? How is it "not working" exactly? (Look into the error.log. Also remove the `<IfModule>` encasing.)

Comment: Hello @mario , I tried `myurl/apresentacao/` and don't work, just with `myurl/apresentacao.php`. I put another URL and updated the question! Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Name a complete URL as example, explain the directory structure, which one's your DOCUMENT_ROOT, and if the `.htaccess` is indeed located there.

Comment: @mario , an entire url will be `www.mydomain.com/software+escolar/gestao+escolar/` to access the page `escolar.php`. My directory structure is simple, the root folder has the file `escolar.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only going to answer the question part where you gave enough details on:

```
RewriteRule ^software+escolar/gestao+escolar/?$ /escolar.php [NC,L]
```

While your input URL might use `+` or `%20` to denote spaces, the RewriteRule sees the actual virtual path name. That is `mod_rewrite` should match for literal spaces there. A `+` in the regex would still be a quantifier.

So what you ought to use is:

```
RewriteRule ^software\sescolar/gestao\sescolar/?$  ...
```

Or even just an escaped space `\␣` in place of `\s` there.

Comment: In case you want to further concretise proplem details, edit your question. Don't add comments here.

Comment: Its not being called yet. I put it on my `.htaccess` and the address `www.mydomain.com/software+escolar/gestao+escolar/` don't work. Should I configure something else?

Comment: Problem solved! I was putting `[L]` what finish the read of the file before read the others **RewriteRule**. Thank you @mario .